# $f(x,y)=\frac{(x,y)}{\|(x,y)\|^2}$ - Show that $f$ is not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

> Let $f: \mathbb{R^2}-\{(0,0)\} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ difined as 
>   $f(x,y)=\frac{(x,y)}{\|(x,y)\|^2}$. Show that $f$ is not uniformly
>   continuous.

I tried to solve it in using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but something blocked. I think at the end, we can use Geometric-Mean inequality, but it's unclear.

Is anyone could give me a hint to solve this problem?

Comment: consider why it's impossible to extend this map continuously from the punctured disk to the disk.

Comment: @CarlChristian You should know that I am at the beginning of an analysis class. So I can't use the derivative for now. The best I can do is to consider the continuity and verify the $\epsilon$ depends on what.

Comment: you posted that response in the wrong place.

Comment: you should put relevant constraints in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I invite you to review the policies of the website. We don't want to overload the question itself to keep some cleanliness of the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the restriction of $f$ to the positive real line, say, $g(x) = 1/x$. Show that this function is not uniformly continuous, by writing
\begin{equation}
g(x_1) - g(x_2) = \frac{x_2 - x_1}{x_1 x_2}
\end{equation}
and letting $x_1, x_2$ tend to zero.

Comment: It's possible for a uniformly continuous function to have an unbounded derivative.

Comment: You are perfectly correct. I was wrong to refer to the derivative. I will update the text.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider $f(1/4^n,0) - f(1/2^n,0)$ as $n\to \infty.$

Comment: No, $f(x,0) = (1/x,0).$

Comment: zhw Oops didn't see the squared denom. Erasing comment.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon=1$ then there is no $\delta>0$ such that any two points within $\delta$ (and neither being $(0,0)$) have their $f$ images within $1$, since one can consider diametrically opposite point $(\pm a,0)$ which for small enough nonzero $a$ are within $\delta$ of each other, yet their $f$ images are $(1,0),(-1,0)$ and are $2$ units apart.

Edit: I didn't notice the denominator is squared, to that the points $(\pm a,0)$ I used actually map to $(\pm(1/a),0).$ For small $a$ this distance is still greater than 1...